Prove that if $\operatorname{rank}(A)$ = $\operatorname{rank}(AB)$, $\operatorname{Range}(A)$ = $\operatorname{Range}(AB)$
I want to prove this by showing subsethood in both directions. The forward direction is easy enough.
Suppose $A$ is a $m \times n$ matrix and $B$ is a $n \times p$ matrix, and $\operatorname{rank}(A) = \operatorname{rank}(B)$. Then
$$
(AB)x = A(Bx) \in \operatorname{Range}(A)
$$
and so $\operatorname{Range}(AB) \subset \operatorname{Range}(A)$.
I don't know how to do the reverse direction, and I am not allowed to use the assumption that if their Ranges have the same dimension, then subsethood in one direction proves they are both equal. I have to prove it more explicitly.
For every $x \in \operatorname{Range}(A)$, it's also true that $x \in \operatorname{Range}(AB)$.

The matrix $AB$ has columns which are linear combinations of the columns of $A$ using the weights given by $B$ so that the column space of $AB$ is a subspace of the column space of $A$ -- this is what you have shown so far.
Let $\mathcal{B}=\{\mathbf{b}_1, ..., \mathbf{b}_p\}$ be a basis for the column space of $AB$, made from choosing $\text{Rank}(AB)$ linearly independent columns of $AB$.  Since the ranks are equal, and each vector in $\mathcal{B}$ is also in the column space of $A$, $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for the column space of $A$.  (**)  Thus, each vector $\textbf{x} \in \text{Range}(A)$ is a linear combination of the vectors in $\mathcal{B}$, which themselves are some of the columns of $AB$. Thus, $\mathbf{x} \in \text{Range}(AB)$.
(**)  But, this is equivalent, essentially to saying that when, for finite vector spaces, if $X$ is a subspace of $Y$ and they have the same dimension, then $X=Y$.  So, I don't know if this satisfies the restriction you mention above about how the proof should go. This is more explicit about why, in this particular case, it works.
